# InvalidOperationException when using threading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I got InvalidOperationException in my Forms application. I create new thread in button click event method:

```
private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        presenter.RunAlgorithm();
    }));

    thread.Start();

}
```

There is the code when I got exception:

```
public string Distance
    {
        get { return cbo_DistanceMeasure.SelectedValue.ToString(); }
    }
```

This property get selected by user value of comboBox. Then this value is used in presenter class in method RunAlgorithm(). I read that for this kind of exception I must use Thread-Safe Calls to controls, like in this article: [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28VS.80%29.aspx). But how use this in my scenario, when I used MVP pattern with Properties to set-get controls value ? Is possible to use delegate with Properties, because I've got more properties which work with controls.

Comment: You should probably read all of the values in the UI thread, then pass them to the background thread.  Also, use `Task` instead of `Thread`.

Comment: I assume this is WinForms but you should tag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to access control from a different thread - its not allowed. In Windows Forms you need to do this:

```
public string Distance
{
    get
    {
        if(this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            return (string)this.Invoke(new Func<string>(this.GetDistance));
        }

        return this.GetDistance();
    }
}

string GetDistance()
{
    return cbo_DistanceMeasure.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

---

WPF:

```
private void btn_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = Dispatcher.Invoke(() => cbo_DistanceMeasure.SelectedValue.ToString(), DispatcherPriority.Background);

    //Do something with the value here, maybe set your property value?
}
```

You can also do directly from property if it can access Dispatcher

```
public string Distance
{
    get
    {
        return Dispatcher.Invoke(() => cbo_DistanceMeasure.SelectedValue.ToString(), DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that this `Dispatcher` class is available only in WPF. My project is Windows Forms App .net 4.0. Maybe some alternative code to this ?

Comment: Ok, your last answer helps me, but now I've got problem in method RunAlgorithm(): `DistanceMetricsTypes distanceType = (DistanceMetricsTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(DistanceMetricsTypes), view.Distance); ` In this code is exception ArgumentNull

Comment: Seems like view.Distance might be null. Did you try to put breakpoint in and see what the value is for the view.Distance?

Comment: Also use the updated code from the get of the property. More cleaner approach

Comment: Exactly is null value.

Comment: Use SelectedValue ONLY when:

the control is bound to a DataSource
AND ValueMember and DisplayMember properties are defined. Try to change the SelectedValue to SelectedItem in the above GetDistance() method

Comment: Ok, now with Func<> look ok. What about properties with set value ? I've got a few which sets `Textbox.Text` properties.

Comment: public string SomeProp
        {
            set
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new Action<string>(this.SetSomething), value);
                    return;
                }

                this.SetSomething(value);
            }
        }

        void SetSomething(string value)
        {
            //set here by accessing Textbox.Text
        }